# Try/catch Image.FromStream() without catching the rest of the using statement?

Tags: c#, try-catch, using, using-statement

`Image.FromStream` throws an `InvalidArgumentException` when you upload something that is not an image.

Therefore I have code similar to this:

```
public void ActionMethod()
{
    try
    {
        using ( var image = Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream) )
        {
            MoreStuffToDo(image);
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidArgumentException e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError( "", "File is not a valid image" );
    }
}
```

Problem is that InvalidArgumentException also catches stuff that has nothing to do with `Image.FromStream`, i.e. in `MoreStuffToDo()`

The only solution I can think of is to remove the using statement. But this also sounds like a bad decission.

What is the right way to do this? So we have both a try/catch around the `Image.FromStream()` method and that the are sure that the image is being properly disposed in all cases?

Comment: Something to note is that even when an exception is thrown with the code you have, your image is still disposed properly.  That is how "using" works.    As soon as the code, now matter how, leaves the using section, the object is disposed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) that's important... it's the call to `IDisposable.Dispose()`. `using` makes that call for you, behind the scenes, allowing you to simply write this:

```
using(var x = new X())
{
    // do stuff with x
}
```

... instead of this:

```
X x = null;
try
{
    x = new X();
    // do stuff with x
}
finally
{
    if(x != null)
    {
        x.Dispose(); // clean up resources
    }
}
```

It's a nice way to skip a bunch of boiler-plate code but you're by no means forced to use it. You can explicitly call `IDisposable.Dispose()` and leave yourself with more control over what happens where:

```
public void ActionMethod()
{
    // declare image...
    Image image = null;

    try
    {
        // attempt to load image from stream...
        image = Image.FromStream(httpPostedFileBase.InputStream)
    }
    catch
    {
        // failed to load image from stream...
        ModelState.AddModelError( "", "File is not a valid image" );
        // exit
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        // perform additional processing...
        MoreStuffToDo(image);
    }
    catch
    {
        // handle errors from MoreStuffToDo()
    } 
    finally
    {
        // clean up image...
        image.Dispose();
    }
}
```